# Java/sql experimental DAO implementation

Tags: java, sql, dao

I am working on a DAO implementation of a database in a Java (web) application. Only I have run into a slight issue.

My current code:

Account.java:

```
package beans;

public class Account {
    private int accountId;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String email;

    public Account() {

    }

    public Account(final String name, final String password, final String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    public void setAccountId(int accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

DAO.java:

```
package dao;

import java.util.Collection;

public interface DAO<T> {
    public int insert(T t);

    public boolean update(T t);

    public T get();

    public Collection<T> search();

    public boolean delete(T t);
}
```

AccountDAO.java:

```
package dao;

import beans.Account;
import java.util.Collection;

public class AccountDAO implements DAO<Account> { 
    @Override
    public int insert(Account t) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean update(Account t) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public Account get() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Account> search() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(Account t) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

The thing is that I am pretty sure that I do not want to use SQL strings already in the `DAO` interface, but then I have the issue of how will I implement `get()` and `search()` properly?

As it is a generic interface, I cannot work with the columns names yet and I would like to keep the `get()` and `search()` methods inside the interface, to ensure that they will be implemented, unless it is really neccessary to remove them from the interface.

My proposed suggestion is to search by a range or by an not-completely filled in object of class T. So if you would want to get the account with name=x, then you would have code like:

```
AccountDAO accountDAO = DAOFactory.getAccountDAO();
Account result = accountDAO.get(new Account(x, null, null));
```

But I am unsure if this would be the best solution, please help me.

Regards.

Comment: Why re-implement the wheel? Won't an existing ORM solve your problems?

Comment: @Thihara I find those difficult to master, I have surely looked around already on the internet, but they all seem so difficult. I would like to start with my application soonish and if I would get this part to work it would seem that it is enough for now.

Comment: Your solution looks clear. What do you think that is wrong with it?

Comment: @skiwi You will waste a lot more time writing your own solution than it would take to use JPA/Hibernate for example. This is really one of these problems that you do NOT want to tackle yourself.

Comment: Ok I've heard the concerns, but I still would like an answer to my actual question if possible.

Comment: What's the exact problem with your `get()` and `search()` methods?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I tackled mine:

I created an abstract class `NativeQueryBasedDAO` that accepts SQL queries. This way, I can have subclasses that extends `NativeQueryBasedDAO` that represents eeach RDBMS (like MySQL, DB2, PostGres, etc.).

In your case, you will have something of this effect:

```
public abstract class NativeQueryBasedDAO<T> implements DAO<T> {

    private Connection connection;
    private String schemaName;
    private String tableName;

    protected NativeQueryBasedDAO(Connection connection, String tableName) {
        this(connection, null, tableName);
    }

    protected NativeQueryBasedDAO(Connection connection, String schemaName, String tableName) {
        if (schemaName == null) {
            this.schemaName = "";
        } else {
            this.schemaName = schemaName;
        }
        this.connection = connection;
        this.tableName = tableName;
    }

    protected final String getTableName() {
        return tableName;
    }

    protected final String getSchemaName() {
        return schemaName;
    }

    protected final Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }
}
```

The above fields can help you in methods such as `get()` where you need to get an Object based on your `schemaName + tableName`.

Then, I would have an `Factory<T>` that has a `public T create()` that creates an object (in your case, account).

So, based on some `Parameters, you can pass/generate a`Factory` that will generate an object.

You can then modify your `DAO` to do a `get(Criteria criteria)` that builds a `Factory` with parameters to populate to create your object.

In a nutshell, it is not a simple solution (as this must be robust and grow based on your requirement). ORM such as Hibernate or JPA implementations (e.g. TopLink) handles this.

I hope this helps.